# Solr query giving wrong results searching multi-word (separated by space) string

Tags: solr

I have indexed following document in Solr with **app_name** is multi-word string eg."Fire inspection" ,

```
{
    "app_name":"Fire inspection",
    "appversion":1,
    "id":"app_1397_version_2417",
    "icon":"/images/media/default_icons/app.png",
    "type":"app",
    "app_id":1397,
    "account_id":556,
    "app_description":"fire inspection app",
    "_version_":1599441252925833216}]
}
```

if i execute following Solr query, Solr returning wrong response,

Query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/AxoSolrCollectionLocal/select?fq=app_name:*fire P*&q=*:*
```

I'm searching for record's whose app_name contains "fire P" but getting -response whose app_name contains "fire inspection". Here, string 'Fire P' does not match with below record but still it is responded by Solr.

```
Response:
{
    "app_name":"Fire inspection",
    "appversion":1,
    "id":"app_1397_version_2417",
    "icon":"/images/media/default_icons/app.png",
    "type":"app",
    "app_id":1397,
    "account_id":556,
    "app_description":"fire inspection app",
    "_version_":1599441252925833216}]
}
```

Can someone please help me with the Solr query (same as that of like query in SQL) which will check for substring and spaces will not be mattered.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - your query does not mean what you think it means. `app_name:*fire P*` means "search for anything ending in `fire` in the field `app_name` and/or anything starting with `p` in the default search field". Since you haven't prefixed the second value with a field name, the default search field will be used.

If you want to search for a substring match inside a field like that (i.e. something that contains "fire P" as a substring inside the value, the field type has to be made a string field - or a field with a keyword tokenizer - that way the field retains its actual value, and it's not processed / filtered / tokenized further. If it's being tokenized, those tokens (i.e. `fire`, `inspection` etc) will be stored separately. You'll have to escape any spaces properly and query a single field (i.e. app_name:*fire\ P*`), and depending on the use case, performance may take a hit unless you have the ReversedWildcardFilter enabled as well.

However, you can probably also use the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) to get support for wilcards in phrase queries:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}app_name:"*fire P*"
```

should work, as long as you actually have uppercase letters in your tokens (wildcards disables many filters, so usually you'll want to match the end syntax in your tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the field type from text_general to string and it is working.. However to search all records which contains value "fire P" I have to write the following query: `http://localhost:8983/solr/AxoSolrCollectionLocal/select?fq=app_name:fire\ P*&q=*:*`

Comment: You can use the query directly in `q` if you don't have another query - the behavior will be more or less the same.